# Multi-Column Items with Headers in WPF Combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, header

I would like to have a combobox that displays items with multiple properties showing per item with a column header for the property.  Here is the control template I'm currently working with.  What is the best way to go about adding column headers to these?

My combobox is set to ItemsSource="{Binding Meters}"

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextElement.FontWeight="Normal">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Status" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="ExpectMfactor" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=MtrNo}" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Width="1" Fill="Black" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Status}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="3" Width="1" Fill="Black" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Path=ExpectMfactor}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Assuming you want the column headers to appear once, above the entire list of items, you can't do that by merely re-templating the items themselves. See the related questions in the right sidebar for a multitude of approaches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Multiple item combo box with headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807899/wpf-multiple-item-combo-box-with-headers)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with item template

it's better to use a `DataGrid` or `ListView` Inside `ComboBox`

Comment: That's going to display headers above *every individual item*.