# How to set a ComboBox header using XAML in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I've spent the last few days trying to create a header for my comboBox but I can't seem find a way. All I've found so far couldn't be implemented in my model. I have to say that I have a slim understanding on databinding which I have been doing some serious reading on.
I created a comboBox and filled it with data from different databases. Then, I used a converter to concatenate relevant data to be displayed. Now I would like to add a header describing the name of each section. 
Here is my XAML:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:ConcatenateFieldsMultiValueConverter x:Key="converter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<ComboBox Name="PersonComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="465">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox x:Name="ComboBoxCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <TextBlock> 
                            <TextBlock.Text> 
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}" ConverterParameter=", ">
                                    <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                                    <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Age"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Country"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
```

Here is where I bound to the comboBox:

```
    // Binds the comboBox to the personDataItems list
    this.PersonComboBox.ItemsSource = personDataItems;
```

This is how the header should look:
[image]

I want to be able to do it using XAML. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Can you provide us with a picture of what are you trying to achieve? It seems the simple binding should be enough in this case without any value converters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple item combo box with headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807899/multiple-item-combo-box-with-headers)

Comment: @safetyOtter I have already looked into it.However, this solution suggests that I change the core of my XAML. I have been working on modifying my XAML so that it reflects the changes needed.I was hoping somebody could lead me on a different track.

Comment: @grizzly the reason I used a converter is because I'm getting FirstName and LastName from the same database whereas Age and Country are from the same but different database from the former. The main goal is to display in the comboBox an entry with all these properties combined: FirstName, LastName, Age, Country. I've added how the header should look like. 
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109323/is-it-possible-to-define-variable-number-of-columns-of-a-combobox-in-resource-di/22269373#22269373 .same you have edit template for toggle button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Xaml code**

```
<Window x:Class="Multiple_Colum_Cmb.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Multiple_Colum_Cmb"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <local:ComboboxData x:Key="ComboboxData"></local:ComboboxData>

    <!--datatemplate-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Datatemplate">
        <Grid  SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="0,0,30,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Firstname}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Foreground="Black" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="15" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Foreground="Black" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"  Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"  Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--header text-->
    <TextBlock x:Key="header1" Text="FirstName"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Key="header2" Text="LastName"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Key="header3" Text="Age"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Key="header4" Text="Country"></TextBlock>

    <!--Toggle Button Template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid x:Name="gd">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"></ContentPresenter>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header1},Path=Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" FontSize="15" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header2},Path=Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header3},Path=Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header4},Path=Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1"/>
            <Border x:Name="Boredr1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Boredr1" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0 0 L 5 5 L 10 0"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.5"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="gd" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!--TextBox Template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!--Multiple column combobox-->
    <Style x:Key="Multiple_Column_Cmb" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Foreground="Black" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBox OverridesDefaultStyle="True" SelectionBrush="Gray" CaretBrush="Black" Margin="0,0,30,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap"   x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" FontFamily="Segoe UI Dark"   Foreground="Black" Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Focusable="True"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="15"   Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup Name="Popup"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placement="Bottom"  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <ContentControl Name="DropDown"   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Grid  Background="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border  x:Name="DropDownBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Transparent" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent">
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!--combobox item style-->
    <Style x:Key="Column_CmbItem" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1,0,1,1" Background="White">
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox x:Name="Combobox1" IsReadOnly="True"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Datatemplate }" Margin="0,0,50,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  IsEditable="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ComboboxData}}" Style="{StaticResource Multiple_Column_Cmb}" Height="30" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Column_CmbItem}"  Width="400"/>            
</Window>
```

**C# code**

```
InitializeComponent();
List<ComboboxData> cmb = new List<ComboboxData>();
cmb.Add(new ComboboxData("oliver", "stone", "30", "USA"));
cmb.Add(new ComboboxData("Joseph", "Truan", "35", "Canada"));
Combobox1.ItemsSource = cmb;

 public class ComboboxData
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public ComboboxData(string Firstname, string LastName, string Age, string Country)
    {
        this.Firstname = Firstname;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.Country = Country;
    }

    public ComboboxData() { }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Update :**
I have designed two tempale for togglebutton

1) When combobox item is not selected ie.selectdeindex=-1 (**NoItemselected**)

2) Default template(**ShowselectedItem**)

```
 <!--header text-->
    <TextBlock x:Key="header1" Text="FirstName"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Key="header2" Text="LastName"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Key="header3" Text="Age"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Key="header4" Text="Country"></TextBlock>

    <!--Toggle Button Template1-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="NoItemselected" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid x:Name="gd">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"></ContentPresenter>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header1},Path=Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" FontSize="15" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header2},Path=Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header3},Path=Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header4},Path=Text}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1"/>
            <Border x:Name="Boredr1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Boredr1" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0 0 L 5 5 L 10 0"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.5"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="gd" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!--Toggle Button Template2-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ShowselectedItem" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid x:Name="gd">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"></ContentPresenter>                
            <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1"/>
            <Border x:Name="Boredr1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Boredr1" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0 0 L 5 5 L 10 0"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.5"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="gd" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!--TextBox Template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!--Multiple column combobox-->
    <Style x:Key="Multiple_Column_Cmb" TargetType="ComboBox">                        
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource ShowselectedItem}" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press"/>                                                                                  
                        <ContentPresenter  Name="ContentSite"  IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />                              
                        <TextBox OverridesDefaultStyle="True" SelectionBrush="Gray" CaretBrush="Black" Margin="0,0,30,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap"   x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" FontFamily="Segoe UI Dark"   Foreground="Black" Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Focusable="True"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="15"   Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup Name="Popup"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placement="Bottom"  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <ContentControl Name="DropDown"   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Grid  Background="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border  x:Name="DropDownBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Transparent" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent">
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>                         
                        <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                            <Setter Property="Template" TargetName="ToggleButton" Value="{StaticResource NoItemselected}"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>                
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>                            
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>                    
    </Style>
```