# WPF ComboBox Multiple Columns

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I am just wondering if there is a wpf combobox control that can contain multiple columns?

And if not, what XAML I need to use to achieve this?

I am just looking for a basic two column combobox if is possible,

Thanks

Comment: In wpf any control can be modified via template...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109323/is-it-possible-to-define-variable-number-of-columns-of-a-combobox-in-resource-di/22269373#22269373

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please Refer these links for **Multiple Column Combobox** which is implemented by editing combox and comboboxitem  Default template/style.

> 1)[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109323/multiple-item-combo-box-with-headers-in-resource-dictionary/22269373#22269373)
>
> 2)[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338088/how-to-set-a-combobox-header-using-xaml-in-wpf)

**Xaml code** : Please take a look at commented **Trigger IsHighlighted** in ComboboxItem style

```
 <Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="30" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">                
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="gd" TextElement.Foreground="Black">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding State}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Population}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                                    <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                                    <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>

                                <!--IsHighlighted and IsMouseOver is showing same effect but IsHighlighted is used for showing logical focus( for understanding check using tab key)-->

                                <!--<Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                                    <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>-->
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**c# code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window

{

    private ObservableCollection<City> cities = new ObservableCollection<City>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Mumbai", State = "Maharashtra", Population = 3000000 });
        cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Pune", State = "Maharashtra", Population = 7000000 });
        cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Nashik", State = "Maharashtra", Population = 65000 });
        cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Aurangabad", State = "Maharashtra", Population = 5000000 });
        DataContext = cities;
    }
}

class City
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: FWIW, this answer looks startling like [this guide](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/multi-columns-combo-box/).

Answer (score 4):

Because I found, Heena, that your Xaml does not provide selected dropped down items to be highlighted I modified your code as follows:

**Xaml**

```
<ComboBox Name="cbCities" Height="30" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding State}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Border Name="templateBorder" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter>
                                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding State}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Population}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ContentPresenter.Content>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="templateBorder" Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

**C#**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Boston", State = "MA", Population = 3000000 });
    cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Los Angeles", State = "CA", Population = 7000000 });
    cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Frederick", State = "MD", Population = 65000 });
    cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Houston", State = "TX", Population = 5000000 });
    cbCities.DataContext = cities;
}

class City
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I know im late but this is how you do it in a simplified way, After the `DataTemplate` tag you can put anything depending on how  you want your lay out to look like.

```
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundMainBrush}"
                                           Margin="5 0"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoBold}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Run  Text="Code :" />
                                    <Run Text="{Binding ActivityCode,Mode=OneWay}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundDarkBrush}"
                                           Margin="5 0"
                                           Text="|"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoBold}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundMainBrush}"
                                           Margin="5 0"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoBold}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Run  Text="Rate :" />
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Rate,Mode=OneWay}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

> Result

[Sample Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkhEm.jpg)

> Or Use a readonly property in your DataModel as shown on the code below and set your combobox DisplayMemberPath to **`DisplayMemberPath="CodeRate"`**

```
 public string ActivityCode { get; set; }
 public string Rate { get; set; }
 public string CodeRate => string.Format("Code: {0} | Rate: 
 {1}",ActivityCode,Rate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use StackPanels in mine. Maybe kind of redundant per item, but it got me exactly the solution I wanted without getting too deep into things.

```
        <ComboBox Name="cboTask">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBoxItem Name="someTask" Content="Doing Some Task" /><Button Name="cmdDetails" Content="..." />
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBox>
```