# How to create and style a two-column ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, styles

I have used `Styles` and `ControlTemplate` to change the appearance of the `ComboBox` and `ComboBoxItem`. Now The final appearance is as below.

[image]

Now what I want is to somehow change the template of the `ComboBoxItem` so that it looks like below. I don't want the instructions on how to draw the colored rectangles. Just how to create the two-column template and how to update it.

[image]

Here is the code I have used to achieve the first image:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />


<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Width="188" Height="23" Fill="{StaticResource NormalImg}"></Rectangle>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource PressedImg}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource NormalImg}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint" Value="Enabled"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="188"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton 
    Name="ToggleButton" 
    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
    Grid.Column="2" 
    Focusable="false"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter
    Name="ContentSite"
    IsHitTestVisible="False" 
    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
    Margin="7,0,0,3"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
    Style="{x:Null}" 
    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Margin="3,3,23,3"
    Focusable="True" 
    Background="Transparent"
    Visibility="Hidden"
    IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup 
    Name="Popup"
    Placement="Bottom"
    IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    Focusable="False"
    PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid 
        Name="DropDown"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
        MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
        x:Name="DropDownBorder"
        Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
        Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint" Value="Enabled"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Border 
    Name="Border"
    Padding="2"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="true" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ComboBox Width="188" Height="23" Margin="0 1 0 0" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}">
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}">Model</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}">Columns Layout</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}">Column Elevations</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}">Column Sections</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}">Beams Layout</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}">Beam Elevations</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}">Floors Layout</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: how do you want to set the second image / progress bar value from combo box item?

Comment: @YuliamChandra That's one of my main problems. I'd prefer to set it via code.

Comment: to display image in the combobox area visit this..may be helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084576/wpf-combobox-multiple-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the easiest solution to use the `Tag` property.

```
<ComboBox Width="188" Height="23" Margin="0 1 0 0" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}">
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" Tag="10">Model</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" Tag="20">Columns Layout</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" Tag="30">Column Elevations</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" Tag="40">Column Sections</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" Tag="50">Beams Layout</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" Tag="60">Beam Elevations</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" Tag="70">Floors Layout</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Then update your `ComboBoxItemStyle Template`.

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <!-- other code omitted -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Border  Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" />
                        <ProgressBar Grid.Column="2" Value="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Maximum="100" Width="100"></ProgressBar>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <!-- other code omitted -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

PS: The expected UI might not really close to what you want, but it will give you idea where to start.

Comment: Thank you so much Yuliam, this is actually a genius idea to do it like this. But when I select an item and close the popup I also want the image to be displayed in the combobox area.

Comment: @Vahid, you need to also modify the ComboBox Template :)

Comment: Can you please tell me where should I change. I'd be very grateful, I tried but I failed.

Comment: @Vahid, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) copy paste the default template and start figuring out where to put the grid :)

Comment: Thanks Yuliam, I'll try from the scratch. Just one more thing that I noticed. When we change the controltemplate of the combobox like this, it seems that it gets a bit slow when the mouse pointer is moving through its items. Have you noticed that too?

Comment: @Vahid, yup I noticed, maybe the Binding selector to Tag is not efficient, or maybe it took time to cast object to integer, ideally create a custom data context for each combo box itme

Comment: custom datacontext for each combobox? Then I'll need to change the style too? I'm really lost :(

Comment: perhaps adjusting the style too, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list) how to bind combo box

Comment: Thanks Yuliam, I'll try the articles you gave me and if needed I'll start a bounty for the complete answer in two days.