# How can I filter more than one column in a WPF combobox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm trying to make a `ComboBox` with multiple filtering, I have a data template with two `TextBlocks` that can show 2 columns and a `textSearch.path` that can filter just one of the columns and I wonder if there is a way to filter in both columns, something like a lookup edit on DevExpress.

Comment: Probably you could filter the datasource you bind

Comment: Visit Link1 In this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084576/wpf-combobox-multiple-columns/23085288?noredirect=1#comment38960771_23085288