# Styled WPF ComboBox not showing scroll bars

Tags: wpf, combobox, scrollbar, multiple-columns

I have a styled multi column ComboBox that is not showing scroll bars even if there is a lot of items in combo box.
it works normally when there are a few items.
But the problem is that whenever items are more then viewable area, there is no scrollBars to scroll the contents.

Resource Dictionary:

```
<!--+++++++++++++++combo1+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
<!--header text-->
<TextBlock x:Key="header1" Text="LastName"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Key="header2" Text="Name"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Key="header3" Text="ID"></TextBlock>

<!--Toggle Button Template-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid x:Name="gd">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="White" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Border x:Name="Boredr1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
        <Path x:Name="Arrow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"/>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" TextElement.Foreground="Orange"></ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Boredr1" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0 0 L 5 5 L 10 0"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.5"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="gd" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!--TextBox Template-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
</ControlTemplate>

<!--2 column combobox-->
<Style x:Key="2_Column_Cmb" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Foreground="Black" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox OverridesDefaultStyle="True" SelectionBrush="Gray" CaretBrush="Black" Margin="0,0,30,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap"   
                             x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" FontFamily="B Koodak"   Foreground="Black" 
                             Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Focusable="True"  
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="15"   Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup Name="Popup" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placement="Bottom"  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Background="LightGray"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header2},Path=Text}" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" 
                                           FontFamily="B Titr" FontSize="13" ></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Background="LightGray"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header3},Path=Text}" Background="LightGray" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" 
                                           FontFamily="B Titr" FontSize="13"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="DropDownBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Transparent" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent">
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"  Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"  Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter  TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!--3 column combobox-->
<Style x:Key="3_Column_Cmb" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" 
                                  Foreground="Black" 
                                  Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Focusable="false" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                  ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" 
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3"  
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" 
                             SelectionBrush="Gray" CaretBrush="Black" Margin="0,0,30,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap"   
                             FontFamily="B Koodak"   Foreground="Black" 
                             Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             Focusable="True"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="15"   Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup Name="Popup"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placement="Bottom"  
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                        <ContentControl Name="DropDown"   
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                        MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" 
                                        MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid Background="LightGray"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header1}, Path=Text}"  
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                               Foreground="Black" FontFamily="B Titr" FontSize="13" >
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Background="LightGray"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header2}, Path=Text}" 
                                               Background="LightGray" 
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                               Foreground="Black" FontFamily="B Titr" FontSize="13"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Background="LightGray"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource header3}, Path=Text}"
                                               Background="LightGray" 
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                               Foreground="Black" FontFamily="B Titr" FontSize="13"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"  
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Transparent" 
                                        MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
                                              Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent">
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!--combobox item style-->
<Style x:Key="Column_CmbItem" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Grid x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1,0,1,1" Background="White">
                    <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<!--++++++++END OF combo1+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
```

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox Margin="24,39,26,0" Name="comboBox2" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
      IsEditable="True" 
      IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
      ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalFirst"
      ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"

      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
      Style="{StaticResource 3_Column_Cmb}" 
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Column_CmbItem}" Tag="Item1" Width="321" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">

<TextSearch.TextPath>LastName</TextSearch.TextPath>

<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Grid.Column="0" 
                       FontSize="15" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Foreground="Black" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Grid.Column="1" 
                       FontSize="15" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Foreground="Black" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       Grid.Column="2" 
                       FontSize="20"  Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

c#:

```
List<Combo3Col> Combo3ColItems = new List<Combo3Col>();
for (int i=0; i < 30; i++)
{
    Combo3ColItems.Add(new Combo3Col { LastName = "TestLastName", Name = "TestName", Code = "1354501" });
}
foreach (Combo3Col item in Combo3ColItems)
{
    comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
}

class Combo3Col
{
    private string lastname;

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value; }
    }
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private string code;

    public string Code
    {
        get { return code; }
        set { code = value; }
    }

}
```

Could anybody help me please?
Best regards

Comment: Glad to know you are using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109323/multiple-item-combo-box-with-headers-in-resource-dictionary/22269373#22269373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your second row of the Grid in the style 3_Column_Cmb is set to Auto

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
```

For some reason the ScrollViewer thinks it has unlimited space and doesn't show the scrollbars. A workaround is to eliminate both rows and position the ScrollView via the margin (I chose 30 from the top):

```
    <Style x:Key="3_Column_Cmb" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton"
                                      ClickMode="Press"
                                      Focusable="false"
                                      Foreground="Black"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,
                                                          Mode=TwoWay,
                                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite"
                                          Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                          IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                 Margin="0,0,30,0"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 CaretBrush="Black"
                                 Focusable="True"
                                 FontFamily="B Koodak"
                                 FontSize="15"
                                 Foreground="Black"
                                 IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                                 OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                                 SelectionBrush="Gray"
                                 Style="{x:Null}"
                                 Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                                 TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                 Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <Popup Name="Popup"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                               AllowsTransparency="True"
                               Focusable="False"
                               IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                               Placement="Bottom"
                               PopupAnimation="Fade">
                                <Grid MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                            MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                            MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                                          Grid.Column="0"
                                          Background="LightGray">
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                   FontFamily="B Titr"
                                                   FontSize="13"
                                                   Foreground="Black"
                                                   Text="h1" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                            MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                            Background="Transparent"
                                            BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                            BorderThickness="1"
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          Background="LightGray">
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                   Background="LightGray"
                                                   FontFamily="B Titr"
                                                   FontSize="13"
                                                   Foreground="Black"
                                                   Text="h2" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                                          Grid.Column="2"
                                          Background="LightGray">
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                   Background="LightGray"
                                                   FontFamily="B Titr"
                                                   FontSize="13"
                                                   Foreground="Black"
                                                   Text="h3" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                                  Margin="0,30,0,0"
                                                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="True" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <!--<Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />-->
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <!--<Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />-->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thank you gomi42 for your answer. Now I want contents to scroll, concurrently with scrollBar. the current scrollBar moves content after mouseUp event. Could anybody help me do that?

Comment: Hm, in my test environment the content moves smoothly directly linked to the scrollbar. Did you modify the style? Or do you have anther scollbar style that might influence the scrollbar behavior?

Comment: Yes I did. I defined custom scroll bar, but the problem is not because of that. I copied the codes in this page into a blank solution, the problem exists!